# How to get an answer in java using JDBC for SQL query which returns true?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

SQL query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE id = 1
)
THEN TRUE 
ELSE FALSE END
```

via phpMyAdmin i get: 1 as the answer for the query
but i can not get this response by `statement.execute()`

Comment: to run a query you should use `executeQuery()` not `execute()`

Comment: I know that with executeQuery() I got ResultSet, bur how can I get the response? I mean how to get from ResultSet the answer for SQL query

Comment: `ResultSet.getBoolean()` or (as MySQL does not have a proper boolean data type) maybe `ResultSet.getInt()`

Answer (score 0):

you can get the result from ResultSet using

```
resultset.getBoolean(columnIndex)
```

Comment: Remove ' from column  name.. And print the query before executing so that you can check any syntex error

Comment: thank you.It was useful to check the whole query. Actually I have error because I didn't use resultset.next().